# Django Message framework is not showing message in template

Tags: python, django

Here is my settings file

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
       "django.core.context_processors.request",
       "django.core.context_processors.media",
)
# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '*******************************'
# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (

   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

In template I have added the following code to show up message

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

In my views I am creating message like

```
print results
if results == ():
    messages.success(request, 'This id is not valid key')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/subscriber/login/')
```

I already have imported `from django.contrib import messages`  In the view

I dont know what might I am doing wrong here. I am not able to get any message in the login page.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your context processors to:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
   "django.core.context_processors.request",
   "django.core.context_processors.media",
   "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
)
```

This way django will put all messages to context used to render the templates, and therefore you will have access to `messages` in templates.

BTW. You should never, ever post your `SECRET_KEY` in public. Never.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

EDIT: changed settings excerpt OP provided

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
       "django.core.context_processors.request",
       "django.core.context_processors.media",
       "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
)
# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'h^@hi8e&amp;q4e#h!j4v$x+@y2ngs&amp;3&amp;*o%!u8pi(vp3h8n&amp;0$*a)'
# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (

   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: Nice and thanks but I already added middleWare why that is not working

Comment: that is not middleware, that is context processor. Middleware is used to modify incoming request or rendered response, while context processor is used to modify data sent from your view to your template.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages` to your template context processors list.