# Django not serving text content (First attempt)

Tags: python, html, django

**Summary:**

The purpose of this particular Django web app is to just show some lorem ipsum text on the home page, like a blog post. Django is not serving my blog post content. I know the problem is either with my views.py  or urls.py (or both).

**Details:**

I’ve got the data declared inside my models.py. I’ve got my views.py to instantiate the model. I migrated sqlite and successfully logged into the Admin Dashboard and entered some placeholder data.

I’m trying to get  Django to serve the placeholder content that I entered into the Admin Dashboard, but instead it’s blank.

Here is my what my test case looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh2yK.jpg
To describe it, you can see The Blog Post, Date, Image, and Body Text HTML heading elements parsed, but none of the content is showing.

Here is  my app’s urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.mortems, name='home'),
]
```

I’ve tried swapping out the quotation marks for the first path() parameter with  `alls/landings`. I’ve tried swapping the name parameter from `home` to `mortems`. I also tried using `mortem` (without the `s`). None of these changes help.

I've also tried Googling (with variations):

- 'body text django not showing template'
- 'django not showing text contents'

Which turned up (among other) SO questions and answers which kind of sound related but are completely different from my issue:

- [Django Message framework is not showing message in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236111/django-message-framework-is-not-showing-message-in-template)
- [Why django template is not showing any output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073935/why-django-template-is-not-showing-any-output)

Here is my app’s views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404
from mortems.models import Mortem

def mortems(request):
   mortem = Mortem.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
   context = {'mortem':mortem}
   return render(request, 'alls/landings.html', context)
```

For what it is worth, here are the relevant lines in my model:

```
class Mortem(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=161)
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
   body = models.TextField()
   now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Also, here is my template with the relevant problematic lines (42-50):

```
<h1> BLOG POST:</h1>
<h4>Date: {{ mortem.pub_date_preference }}</h4>
<br />
Image: <img src="{{ mortem.image.url }}" class="img-responsive center-block" style="max-height:300px;" />
<br />
 
<!-- Body text should go here :   -->
Body Text:
<p>{{ mortem.body|safe }}</p>
```

The full source code is up on GitHub. Here is [the 'mortems' app source code](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/tree/16e6da6c6d74236072b75cd8b0ec1c643423431b/mortems) specifically.

For generous SO users with time on their hands, I guess I’m accepting pull requests. haha

Comment: Shouldn't the query be like:
mortem = Mortem.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')

Comment: Thanks, @ManjitKumar: Yes, I needed that. I just added `.all().` to my query call inside my view function. Although this hasn't resolved the original issue yet. So there might be more to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to update the views.py as:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404
from mortems.models import Mortem

def mortems(request):
    mortems = Mortem.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date') # returns an iterable queryset
    context = {'mortems':mortems}  # using plural as it's a list like object
    return render(request, 'alls/landings.html', context)
```

In the template code, you need to iterate over the list to display a single object one at a time. i.e

```html
<h1> BLOG POSTs:</h1>
{% for moertm in mortems} 
  <h4>Date: {{ mortem.pub_date_preference }}</h4>
  <br />
  Image: <img src="{{ mortem.image.url }}" class="img-responsive center-block" style="max-height:300px;" />
  <br />
 
  <!-- Body text should go here :   -->
  Body Text:
  <p>{{ mortem.body|safe }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you @Manjit Kumar for you reply! All your suggestions are valid. I promptly pluralized the instances of ‘mortems’ inside my `views.py` and added the for loop to my template. Here is what my web app landing page looks like now: https://e082f3051c81.ngrok.io/

You can view my diff’s here: https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/commit/88fd0122c015205137256ee89820aeba83f1ebe1