# Django not serving text content (Second attempt)

Tags: python, html, django

**Summary:**

I’m writing a Django web app whose purpose is to showcase a writing sample (a ‘post mortem’) which is basically like a blog post for all intents and purposes. Django is not serving the content and I am not sure why. The problem I figure is with either my views.py or template (copied below). I don’t think the issue is with my models or urls.py but I included them anyways.

**Details:**

This is my second attempt at getting my Django project to serve this template properly. In my prior first attempt, I encountered a similar issue:
[Django not serving text content (First attempt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822839/django-not-serving-text-content-first-attempt)

There in that question, another SO member answered by identifying three mistakes I was making. The problem there was that I was missing a for loop inside my template, I was missing an `all()` class method inside my `views.py` and the `context` dictionary key value pair in `views.py` was not pluralized.

Those issues have been resolved however my new issue involves Django serving a blank template when I am expecting the Lorem Ipsum content to show.

Django should be pulling all the class objects from my models.py and then be sending them to the `alls/landings.html`. I am expecting the title, publication date, image and body content to render on my landing page.  But instead, my ‘mortems’ app content (a blog post) isn’t showing on the landing page. The only thing that shows is the heading. To illustrate so you can see what I see, here is what my landing page looks like now: [image]

Based on what you people see below, who can tell me what is wrong with my views / landings.html template?

The full source code can be found on my GitHub page. [Here is a snapshot](http://v0.6.0.https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/tree/a188b0ca52f947f2452218d868bc770f62e0583f) of the state of my project (tagged as v0.6.0).

What follows are the code samples where I suspect my issue exists.

Here is my latest **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404
from mortems.models import Mortem
 
def mortems(request):
   mortems = Mortem.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
   context = {'mortems':mortems}
   return render(request, 'alls/landings.html', context)
```

Here is my **templates/alls/landings.html**:

```
{% load static %}
 
<html>
<head>
 <title> BLOG </title>
 <style>    </style>
 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'redactors/style.css' %}"> -->
 </head>
 <body>
   {% block content %}   
  <h1> BLOG POST:</h1>
 
 {% for mortem in mortems %}
   <h1>{{ mortem.title }}</h1>
   <h4>Date: {{ mortem.pub_date_preference }}</h4>
   <br />
   Image: <img src="{{ mortem.image.url }}" class="img-responsive center-block" style="max-height:300px;" />
   <br />
    
   <!-- Body text should go here :   -->
   Body Text:
   <p>{{ mortem.body|safe }}</p>
   <br />
   <br />
 {% endfor %}
 
{% endblock %}
 
 </body>
 
</html>
```

Here my project’s main **urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
 
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include('redactors.urls')),
   path('', include('counters.urls')),
   path('', include('mortems.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is my app’s (mortems) **urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
 
 
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.mortems, name='mortems'),
]
```

Here is my app’s **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
 
# Create your models here.
 
class Mortem(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=161)
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
   body = models.TextField()
   now = datetime.datetime.now()
 
   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
 
   def pub_date_preference(self):
       # a = self.pub_date.timezone.now("US")
       b = self.pub_date.strftime("%A %d %B %Y @ %-I:%M:%S %p")
       # c = pytz.timezone("US")
       return (b)
 
   def summary(self):
       return self.body[:1024]
```

Comment: In your urls.py, what happens if you use unique words instead of having them all blank ('')?

Comment: what does it `print(Mortem.objects.all())`prints ?

Comment: Thanks, @MeL! That solved the issue. I wrote about it in my answer but I am not sure why adding a string inside `path()`  as the first parameter fixed my issue. If you could take a look at my answer and explain why, I'd be happy to update my answer with your further clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same path for views.home in **redactors.urls** and views.mortems in **mortems.urls** i.e '/'

**CC_Redact_Iter3/urls.py** you configured in this order

```
urlpatterns = [
   #Django serves urls in the order you gave
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  #1st
   path('', include('redactors.urls')), #2nd
   path('', include('counters.urls')), #3rd
   path('', include('mortems.urls')), #4th
]
```

**redactors/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'), #here you have to change the home path
    path('alls/results', views.results, name='results'),
]
```

**mortems/urls.py**

```
  urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.mortems, name='mortems'), #As you can see views.home is also having same path so change the path for home
    ]
```

In your case

```
def home(request):
    if 'ccEntry' in request.GET:
        number = request.GET['ccEntry']
        redacted_num = 'xxxx xxxx xxxx {}'.format(number[-4:])
        return render(request, 'alls/results.html', {'number':number, 'redacted_num':redacted_num})
    else:
        return render(request, 'alls/landings.html') #this is being rendered instead mortem
```

Change your **CC_Redact_Iter3/urls.py**  and **redactors/urls.py** as shown below

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mortems.urls')),
    path('', include('redactors.urls')),
    path('', include('counters.urls')),
] 
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

  urlpatterns = [
        path('home/', views.home, name='home'), #here you have to change the home path
        path('alls/results', views.results, name='results'),
    ]
```

And the date format in you **mortems/models.py** is Invalid (%-I)

```
  def pub_date_preference(self):
           # a = self.pub_date.timezone.now("US")
           b= self.pub_date.strftime("%A %d %B %Y @ %I:%M:%S %p") #try something like this
           # c = pytz.timezone("US")
           return (b)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @yogendra! You are right that the issue was the order in which my paths were defined inside my two urls.py's. Everything runs as intended now. I also corrected my date / time format. Thanks again, my friend! :)

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of **@MeL** in the comments, the solution is to include `‘mortems’` as the first argument inside my `path()` function inside the mortems app’s urls.py. This file looks like this now:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('mortems', views.mortems, name='mortems'),
]
```

Now when I navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/mortems`, the `landings.html` template renders exactly as intended, with all the content present. To see, here is my mortems page now:

[image]

So that is the solution I guess. But I remain flummoxed and curious: why?  With the path parameter empty `’’`, I’d expect Django to serve the `landings.html` template on the home page / landing page at this location: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. Django serves the template but all the content is missing. Only after adding a string as an argument the content shows. Why is that?

If someone could kindly answer why, I’d be happy to update this answer here with more information.

Comment: Django will match the first url it can find, so if you leave all blank it will redirect everything to the home page... or to the same page at least.

Comment: Thank you @MeL. If I leave it that `path()` argument blank, Django should redirect everything to the home page, as you say. This is what I originally wanted: the home page should be the `landings.html` but why is the content absent only when the `path()` argument is a string?